# What siege constructions might a snake people race use to scale walls?

Tags: warfare, species

In a ~medieval time period, what might a snake people race use to scale city walls? I'm guessing siege towers are still valid. However after that I can't think of less build-intensive ways for them to scale a wall as my current hunch is think,ladders wouldn't work.

For reference my snake people race looks about like the one in the following image.
https://orig00.deviantart.net/b27c/f/2010/287/1/2/gaia___snake_guardian_commish_by_chobaryu-d30q253.png

In case there are issues with the link: The body is mainly that of a large snake. Towards the front there's a torso of sort and two arms and the head is that of a snake.

Comment: I'm thinking some sort of thick pole might be climbable.  Easier to build than a ladder too, all you have to do is cut down a tree and lean it against the wall.

Comment: So the answer of how to fix ladders for snake people isn't in complication, but simplification. I would not have thought of that.

Comment: How about tree trunks, they are found everywhere and if you're lucky you may find some hidden snacks...

Comment: Can't go through it, can't go over it, then let's go UNDER it.

Comment: The creature in the picture has arms. It CAN climb up a ladder. It is possible to climb a ladder by pulling, instead of pushing yourself up. Difficult, but possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Invert your ladder; you need a single pole, as long as the ladder, crossed at regular intervals by support rungs. At the bottom build a wide triangle so it does not tip. What you want is support for the body of the snake, the pole to coil around, so it's hands and arms are free to fight, much like a human standing on a siege ladder (although humans tend to have just one arm free).

The rungs are angled; for a snake any lubrication of the snake ladder should not make much difference (it would for a simple pole, but here lubrication will just cause the body to slip on the rungs closer to the central pole).

The open sides give the snake freedom to uncoil, or to use multiple rungs at once. Like the human ladder, you want the distance between rungs to be about one fifth to one quarter of the body length. For a snake, perhaps a third of their body length, so they have room to wrap a few coils on a rung.

[image]

Comment: Out of curiosity, would the build time of one these be close to the build time of a regular ladder? This one is one of the more intriguing ideas for me.

Comment: I should think no worse than a regular ladder. It actually requires only one long pole, where the regular ladder requires two (one on each side).

Answer (score 5):

For a large serpentine creature, something as simple as a log would be an effective tool for wall scaling, though those could be easily counteracted with lubricants.  A sluice like ladder would also be a viable option.  The basic requirement for slithering up a ramp is basically to increase the friction coefficient, or have parallel surfaces that the body could be wedged between to force its way up.

http://mineforgold.co.nz/wp-content/uploads/Sluice-box.jpg

Comment: If you add grooves to your scaling rod you could turn it into a scaling screw.  It would be more labor-intensive to make, but probably easier to climb.

Comment: Would also reduce the effectiveness of oils/lubricants for halting advance as it would combine the body wedge and the friction elements, as well as increasing the surface area the lubricants would have to cover to be effective.

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to change your snake people's genetic ancestry a little bit, make them anthropomorphic descendants of [Chrysoelea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chrysopelea), flying snakes.

Then your snake people will share the light bone structure and the ability to shape their bodies into pseudo concave wings, allowing them to glide long distances through the air and land without sustaining damage.  With such an anatomy, catapults could become much more than a method for destroying fortress walls.  Catapults could become silent delivery mechanisms for dropping your snake-man shock troops into the enemy fortress, undetected, from above.  (...which is sort of an inverse metaphor for falling into a pit of snakes).

Set up your catapults in proximity of the target walled city.  Split your best shock troops evenly between your catapults and line them up in order of their killing ferocity.  Have the most deadly warriors climb into the catapult baskets and launch them over the walls.  As the reach the tops of their ballistic arcs, have each warrior extend their pseudo-concave wings and glide down softly to the ground within the city.  Immediately following the first launch have all of the remaining lined-up warriors lever the catapult back into firing configuration then have the next deadliest warriors climb aboard.  Repeat until most of your warriors are inside the city, then tear you enemy apart from the inside (...which is sort of an inverse metaphor to swallowing them whole).

Answer (score 2):

I suspect your snakes would be long and scaly. I would suggest they do not need ANYTHING to help them scale the wall. Take a hint from polymers. The snakes form a long polymer living rope, starting from the ground and just growing up the wall, each snake clinging to the next, entwining their bodies. I notice your snakes have arms and hands, useful for climbing up the bodies of other snakes. The wall would be the support mechanism, to prevent them from toppling over.

Cobras, for instance, can extend their body vertically by some length of their body, coiling up, keeping their body stiff and erect by their own muscles.

The rope would become thicker and thicker as more snakes joined and started climbing up and over.